# Splitting string in cell and duplicate Row

Tags: r, string, split

I'm trying to split out the contents of a cell string, and then duplicate all of the corresponding cells in the row into a duplicate row. In looking at other similar questions I'm finding a partial answer, but my results are dropping some of the data, that I still want to keep.
Sample table (although the real one has many more columns and rows)

```
Client <- LETTERS[seq(1:6)]
Package <- c("1", "1 & 2", "2", "1 & 2","1 & 2", "")
Scope <- c("full", "rapid", "partial", "full", "full", "")
Assignee <- randomNames(6)
df <- data.frame(Client, Package, Scope, Assignee)


 Client Package   Scope           Assignee
1      A       1    full     Young, Devante
2      B   1 & 2  rapid     Catholic, Kori
3      C       2 partial      Maxwell, Luke
4      D   1 & 2    full  Vanzant, Giovanni
5      E   1 & 2    full    el-Sadiq, Aaida
6      F                 el-Yousef, Muneera
```

In this table I need to split out the data under "Package" and duplicate the info into a row. If I do the following:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Package = strsplit(as.character(Package), " & ")) %>%
  unnest(Package)
```

I get the Package content split out and the rows duplicated. As shown below in my results, the problem is that the data from "Client F" is omitted from the results. Like the example table, there will be rows in my real data that has not "package data" and I don't want to lose that information.

```
Client Package Scope   Assignee         
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>            
1 A      1       full    Young, Devante   
2 B      1       rapid  Catholic, Kori   
3 B      2       rapid  Catholic, Kori   
4 C      2       partial Maxwell, Luke    
5 D      1       full    Vanzant, Giovanni
6 D      2       full    Vanzant, Giovanni
7 E      1       full    el-Sadiq, Aaida  
8 E      2       full    el-Sadiq, Aaida
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, would this solution work? Use an if_else statement to change the "" to "No package" like this `df %>% 
  mutate(Package = if_else(Package == "", "No package", Package)) %>%
  mutate(Package = strsplit(as.character(Package), " & ")) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(Package))`

Comment: @Tob, that does seem to work, but is there a way to do it that doesn't involve populating the empty cells with data?

Comment: Looks like @Carl has the answer, you could always use an if_else statement to set the Package column back to "" if you wanted to use that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this approach work for you using tidyr's `separate_rows`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Client, ~Package, ~Scope, ~Assignee,
  "A", "1", "full", "Young, Devante",
  "B", "1 & 2", "rapid", "Catholic, Kori",
  "C", "2", "partial", "Maxwell, Luke",
  "D", "1 & 2", "full", "Vanzant, Giovanni",
  "E", "1 & 2", "full", "el-Sadiq, Aaida",
  "F", NA, NA, "el-Yousef, Muneera"
)

df |> separate_rows(Package)

#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   Client Package Scope   Assignee          
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>             
#> 1 A      1       full    Young, Devante    
#> 2 B      1       rapid   Catholic, Kori    
#> 3 B      2       rapid   Catholic, Kori    
#> 4 C      2       partial Maxwell, Luke     
#> 5 D      1       full    Vanzant, Giovanni 
#> 6 D      2       full    Vanzant, Giovanni 
#> 7 E      1       full    el-Sadiq, Aaida   
#> 8 E      2       full    el-Sadiq, Aaida   
#> 9 F      <NA>    <NA>    el-Yousef, Muneera
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: is "|>" similar in function to "%>%"? I realized I'm not entirely sure what that does

Comment: `|>` is the new native pipe in base R introduced in a recent release. You could use `%>%` instead if preferred, or if on an older release of R. `%>%` (from the magrittr package) will do the same.